# Click on a button in the console doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button to change page but when I want to click on it with the console it doesn't work. But with the mouse it works.

This is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/shr2xhNHzcYwTBPJlisQ?p=preview

And I do this in the console : `$('#language_us').click();` or `$('#language_fr').click();` but it doesn't change page.

Have you an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using anchors `<a>` and not button `<button>`.

To fire click on `<a>` you need to use the DOM element, jQuery object `$()` does not work.

Use,

```
$('#language_us')[0].click();
```

---

`.trigger()` or `.click()` triggers a click handler defined explicitly. You need the native click event which is the default functionality of an anchor. So you need to use HTMLElement Object.

If you would have wrote :

```
$('#language_fr').click(function(){
  alert('..')
})
```

The

```
$('#language_fr').click()
```

would have fired the `alert()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#language_us').trigger('click');
$('#language_fr').trigger('click');
```

Or may be try:

```
$('#language_us').get(0).click();
$('#language_fr').get(0).click();
```

Comment: @MartelBenjamin What exactly did you do?

Comment: @MartelBenjamin Try `$('#language_fr').get(0).click();`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change the tag from `a` to `button` or put a `button` tag inside the `a` tag and press that.