# Facing a issue with .trigger('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link -

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="download_btn" class="btn" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#download_btn').trigger('click');
})
```

But it is not opening the window. What could be the issue?

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vLLoy86/)

Comment: for me either working fine

Comment: It is working when I click on the link. But `click` event need to be triggered automatically.

Comment: check if your browsers has blocked popups. enable it/allow it

Comment: Refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30798203/3639582

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggering the `click` event using jQuery may not always trigger the default action.

One solution to this is to call the click method of the dom element, but still the 
browser may block the popup

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#download_btn')[0].click()
})
```

Comment: The reason is because, the `trigger()` fires jQuery click handlers, original click of an `<a>` has to be fired on DOM element. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30798203/3639582

Comment: Can I use `chaining` with this with some `delay`?

Comment: @b0s3 `Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.` - https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

Comment: @ShaunakD not really... it also triggers non jQuery handlers - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/133fbgee/3/

Comment: Ohh sorry. I didn't mean *just* jQuery click handlers. `:)`. But click handlers in general.

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering the click on the DOM-element directly worked for me:

```
$('#download_btn').get(0).click();
```

As far as I can see, trigger() only executes events bound with on():
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger ()`triggers if an event handler is attached to the element.  Read more about it  here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

You can use `.click ()`to simulate click event on the element.